# Android (JSONObject) How can get each key

Tags: android, json

If I have a JSON:

```
{"list_path":{"149":{"1610":{"file":[]},"1599":{"1600":{"1604":{"1605":{"file":[]},"file":[]},"1601":{"1602":{"file":["f485","f484","f482","f481","f480","f479","f478","f477"]},"file":[]},"file":[]},"file":[]},"1609":{"file":[]},"1607":{"file":[]},"1608":{"file":[]},"1606":{"file":[]},"file":[]}}}
```

But I don't know the key. How can I get each key.

I try to use `String key = iter.next();` but it only can get one key.

Like If I write in 149. I want get 1599, 1606, 1607, 1608, 1609, 1610, file.

Please help me. Thank you.

```
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject jsons = jParser.getJSONFromUrl("http://ap2.finance.xcom.tw:8080/app/?m=z8Ga37UPPQbEDMxR&mode=get_list&user_id=1");

try {
    JSONObject status = jsons.getJSONObject("list_path");
    Iterator iter = status.keys();

    while(iter.hasNext()) {
        String key = (String)iter.next();
        try {
            Object value = jsons.get(key);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d( "Json", "hasNext error");    
        }
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(yourJsonString);
JSONObject listPathObject = obj.getJSONObject("list_path");
JSONObject object149 = listPathObject.getJSONObject("149");
Iterator<String> iter = object149.keys(); //This should be the iterator you want.
while(iter.hasNext()){
    String key = iter.next();
}
```

You will get keys:

```
1610
1599
1609
1607
1608
1606
file
```

Comment: You didn't get the object of ´149´

Answer (score 0):

parse your json hierarchy through http://json.parser.online.fr/

then check how many JSON-objects are there.
there ur code is right in "list_path" there is only single key.
But inside "149" JSON-Object there are 6 Objects wd integer key and one with "file" keyname.